# SQL Importing Microsoft Access sql dump to Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Microsoft Access SQL dump which I am trying to import using psql -f option but getting errors while importing. So is there a way I can convert this SQL dump to support Postgres format.

I have seen some tools which can covert mdb files to respective tables but they are not retaining relationships and other constrains which existing dump has and I want to retain in the import.

```
# psql -U postgres -f test.sql
psql:test.sql:63: invalid command \Administrators]
psql:test.sql:570: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Use"
LINE 1: Use [master]
        ^
```

The dump contains something like below

```
Use [master]
 GO
 EXEC dbo.sp_dbcmptlevel @dbname=N'test', @new_cmptlevel=90
 GO
 IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
 begin
 EXEC [test].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
 end
 GO
 ALTER DATABASE [test] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF

 . . . .


 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FK_ClassOfService_PBX]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ClassOfService]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClassOfService]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ClassOfService_PBX] FOREIGN KEY([PBX])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PBX] ([ID])
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
. . .
```

So is there a way I can import the data.

Comment: It would be helpful to include the errors you are getting.

Comment: By experience I'd tell you to open the dump with a text editor and one by one go through all the statements and modify them to comply with postgresql standards.

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#Microsoft_Access

Answer (score 1):

You will want to load the dump back into MS Access, then use tools to extract the data from the live MS Access over ODBC or similar. Milen already pointed out that [several are listed on the PostgreSQL wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#Microsoft_Access). There are also generic ETL tools like Talend Studio, Pentaho Kettle, and CloverETL for data migration.

If you can only work with a dump, you'll probably have to convert the syntax by hand.

Comment: I have a dump which I need to convert as this will be used to get installed on clean install of the system.

Comment: @Abhinav Restore it to a machine that has MS Access, convert it for PostgreSQL, dump the PostgreSQL database, and then use the resulting PostgreSQL dump to restore into PostgreSQL on the clean install.

Comment: How to convert to PostgreSQL from MS Access if I import it back in MS Access.

Comment: @Abhinav That's what the links above tell you. There's no simple click-and-go method. Go read the wiki page, try the ExportSQL tool, etc. If you're still stuck when you've tried the methods described there, post a question with specific information about what you have tried and where you got stuck.